# Any way to set VS2013 to start in private browser session?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, browser

I have to copy and paste the url into the in private browser's address bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set "c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" as an extra browser in Visual Studio, and then in the Arguments field add "-private" to the startup arguments.

You can find this by clicking on the small down arrow next to the Start/Play button in the standard toolbar in Visual Studio, and then choose "Browse With...". Or you can just go to "File --> Browse With" In this menu you can add an extra browser.

Comment: What's the argument for Chrome?

Comment: @Jude i think it's "-incognito"